# How to render MbTiles on to the mapView in Mapbox Android SDK

Tags: android, mapbox, mbtiles

How to render MbTiles on to the mapView in Mapbox Android SDK? And I am not able to import MBTilesLayer class.. Should I add any jar file to import it..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news is that MBTiles are no longer supported in the latest version of the Mapbox Android SDK. The good news is that offline tiles are still a feature and the new format is also a simple Sqlite database. For more details I recommend you to check out [this getting started example](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/offline-map/).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply... but previously i have gone through the link you have provided..Even i am successful in downloading the map extent and use it in offline mode. But further i want to render a Arcgis rest services layer on the mapbox map and download it along with the mapbox map for offline use.. if possible give me some solution for my problem.

Comment: @Soumya the offline manager will download tiles that are served by Mapbox servers. That doesn't include third-party data you layer on top of the map separately. An option though, is to use Mapbox Studio to import that data into your own basemap. In that case, everything will be served by Mapbox and captured by the offline feature.

Comment: @zulgaldia  Thank you so much..Your reply to the previous comment helped me a lot.